# Tikz function returning coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

In tikz, is there any way for a decelared function to return a coordinate? What I want to do is something like this:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{test}{1}{\pgfmathparse{({#1},{#1})}}
\newcommand{\testCommand}{
    \tikzmath{
        {\fill test(2) circle [radius=1pt];};%
    }
}
```

But it gives me a lot of incomprehensible errors.

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of coordinate ? A syntax or actual two output function? Notice that in TikZ there are no coordinates only references and their x,y values. You can forexample do something like `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\testCommand#1{\fill (#1,#1) circle [radius=1pt];}
\testCommand{1}
\testCommand{3}
\end{tikzpicture}` instead.

Comment: Welcome! A complete minimal example which we can compile (or try to compile) would likely give us more sense of what you are trying to do and make it easier to help you.